# synchronize database queries java

Tags: java, database, multithreading, callback, synchronized

Hi I have a java program with multiple threads querying an HSQL database. I'm getting some very weird results from the queries and my guess is that the database is not set up to handle many queries at the same time. (Is this even possible in a database?).

What I would like to do then is queue any database queries.

As far as I can tell this is done using the synchronize keyword when making functions in my database object?

My database object looks something like this:

```
public class Database(){
    public Database(){
        connect();
    }

    private void connect(){
        //connect to HSQL database
    }

    public void executeOneTypeOfQuery(){
        ...
        ResultSet rs1 = someStatement.executeQuery();
        //do something with a query
    }

    public void executeAnotherTypeOfQuery(){
        ...
        ResultSet rs2 = anotherStatement.executeQuery();
        //do something with a query
    }

}
```

At the moment I may be calling any combination of executeOneTypeOfQuery() and executeAnotherTypeOfQuery() at the same time in different threads.

Should those two functions have the synchronized keyword? Or will that only stop them calling JUST THAT method twice at the same time?

Am I right in thinking another solution could be making use of callbacks (I don't really understand the syntax here)?
So anywhere in my project I call one of those database functions, I call an intermediate synchronized function, stating which database function I really want to use.

So threads call something like:

```
public synchronized void executeAnyQuery(Function theFunctionIWantToCall, Object[] args){
    //do theFunctionIWantToCall
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? If so what is the syntax with callbacks?

Comment: What do you mean with "very weird results from the queries"? The question is missing a clear problem statement and you're not telling anything about the nature of these queries (are they just SELECTs or do some modify data). Databases in general support parallel queries which are isolated in _transactions_. HSQL might be a bit different here if you're running it in-memory.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html:

> ... making these methods synchronized has two effects:
> 

> * First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

So it's not JUST THAT method, it's any `synchronized` method of the same instance.

Comment: Thanks guys, they are only SELECT queries, and assuming HSQLDB works like you are saying then the problem is probably not with the database object but the SQL itself...I was so sure :/

Comment: I've googled around but could not find definitive documentation on whether HSQLDB supports concurrent access and to what extent.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm I suppose a way to check then would be to add synchronized to every database method then?

Comment: Could you clarify what your actual problem is, i.e. explain us the actual results and the expected results of your queries.

Comment: A SELECT statement is returning different results when neither the SQL or the Database has been modified. It happens when I am running lots of threads concurrently, but not when I only have one thread calling functions in the database.

Comment: I added synchronized to every function and the bug is no longer there. Coincidence? I think not!

Comment: Although: What about multithreading?
HSQLDB 2.2 is fully multithreaded. Both the core engine and the Server. In the MVCC mode, multiple threads can write to the same table while other threads perform SELECT queries.
From http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFAQ.html
What is MVCC mode?

Answer (score 0):

The synchronized keyword locks the function from access by another thread until the function terminates (although it does not guarantee the tread will execute uninterrupted)

For the callback, you would do something like this

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo.doExample();
    }
```

}